# Create Ripple Effect on ListView Item for API < & > 21

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, ripple

I have the below XML and am trying to create a ripple effect onClick. The background of each item in the ListView is black, so ideally the ripple effect would generate some sort of grey color:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/white" />


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/latest_item_question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/white" />
```

The code creates the following. Note that I want to cover pre and post Lollipop:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try create two background one ripple and other without ripple for api pre Lollipop
create in drawable

ripple_gray.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

create in drawable-v21
ripple_gray.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:color="@android:color/white">
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
</ripple>
```

change in your XML layout background using ripple_gray created and add id

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/white" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_gray"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/latest_item_question"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in your ACtivity in onCreate() or where you need

```
findViewById(R.id.viewId).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however this approach did not work. No ripple on click

Comment: I had to add the following and it worked, add it and I will mark as correct:         android:clickable="true"

Comment: I probe it in my phone and worked fine, for api < 21 do not work ripple, I did not know about android:clickable="true", thanks